# How to find more detail gitlab runner log?

Tags: gitlab-ci, pipeline

In my failed GitLab Pipeline , there is nothing useful message in the logs ,where can i find more useful message of how the building failed?

[image]

Comment: Which executor are you using?

Comment: @SergioTanaka i use shell on macos to build ios project